Fatal Error: temp_intermediate_result.xml:1:13: White space is required between the processing instruction target and data. How to fix?
I am in the process of developing an API for validating xml via xsd scheme, but I encounter an error:
[Fatal Error] temp_intermediate_result.xml:1:13: White space is required between the processing instruction target and data.
Intermediate XML is not valid:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/ipkuzne3/MTSProjects/vpnm/SchematronValidation/temp_intermediate_result.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 13; White space is required between the processing instruction target and data.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:206)
    at com.example.schematronvalidation.Validator.SchematronValidatorAPI.extractSchematronRules(SchematronValidatorAPI.java:116)
    at com.example.schematronvalidation.Validator.SchematronValidatorAPI.main(SchematronValidatorAPI.java:28)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)" because "<parameter1>" is null
    at com.helger.schematron.pure.SchematronResourcePure.fromString(SchematronResourcePure.java:530)
    at com.example.schematronvalidation.Validator.SchematronValidatorAPI.validateXmlWithSchematron(SchematronValidatorAPI.java:150)
    at com.example.schematronvalidation.Validator.SchematronValidatorAPI.main(SchematronValidatorAPI.java:31)

My code:
    private static String extractSchematronRules(String xsdFilePath) throws Exception {
        // Абсолютные пути к XSLT файлам
        String isoDSDLIncludePath = "src/main/resources/iso_dsdl_include.xsl";
        String isoAbstractExpandPath = "src/main/resources/iso_abstract_expand.xsl";
        String isoSVRLForXSLT2Path = "src/main/resources/iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl";
        String skeletonPath = "src/main/resources/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_saxon.xsl";

        // Проверка существования файлов
        if (!new File(isoDSDLIncludePath).exists()) {
            System.err.println("File not found: " + isoDSDLIncludePath);
            return null;
        }
        if (!new File(isoAbstractExpandPath).exists()) {
            System.err.println("File not found: " + isoAbstractExpandPath);
            return null;
        }
        if (!new File(isoSVRLForXSLT2Path).exists()) {
            System.err.println("File not found: " + isoSVRLForXSLT2Path);
            return null;
        }
        if (!new File(skeletonPath).exists()) {
            System.err.println("File not found: " + skeletonPath);
            return null;
        }

        // Преобразование XSD в Schematron
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xsdDocument;
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xsdFilePath)) {
            xsdDocument = builder.parse(fis);
        }

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        // Применение первого XSLT преобразования
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(isoDSDLIncludePath)));
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(xsdDocument), new StreamResult(writer));
        String intermediateResult = writer.toString();
//    System.out.println("Intermediate result after first transformation:");
//    System.out.println(intermediateResult);

        // Применение второго XSLT преобразования
        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(isoAbstractExpandPath)));
        writer = new StringWriter();
        try {
            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(intermediateResult)), new StreamResult(writer));
            intermediateResult = writer.toString();
            System.out.println("Intermediate result after second transformation:");
            System.out.println(intermediateResult);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error during second transformation:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        // Удаление всех переводов строк из промежуточного результата
        intermediateResult = intermediateResult.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        // Очистка промежуточного XML-документа от некорректного контента
        intermediateResult = intermediateResult.trim();
        int rootEndIndex = intermediateResult.lastIndexOf("</");
        if (rootEndIndex != -1) {
            intermediateResult = intermediateResult.substring(0, rootEndIndex + 2);
        }

        // Применение третьего XSLT преобразования с параметром sch.exslt.imports
        String tempXmlFilePath = "temp_intermediate_result.xml";
        try (FileWriter tempWriter = new FileWriter(tempXmlFilePath)) {
            tempWriter.write(intermediateResult);
        }

        // Проверка корректности промежуточного XML перед третьим преобразованием
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            db.parse(new File(tempXmlFilePath));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Intermediate XML is not valid:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        transformXmlUsingXsl(tempXmlFilePath, isoSVRLForXSLT2Path);

        // Чтение итогового результата из временного файла
        String finalResult;
        try (FileInputStream tempFis = new FileInputStream("temp_final_result.xml")) {
            finalResult = new String(tempFis.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }

        System.out.println("Final result after third transformation:");
        System.out.println(finalResult);
        return finalResult;
    }

XML:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Файл ИдФайл="ON_RISKNALMON_7700_7700_7710016640770701001_20241017_03fd95f3-ce5d-4ac3-9d4f-7a15e2ccfb22" ВерсПрог="Налогоплательщик ЮЛ" ВерсФорм="5.02">
  <Документ КНД="1125308" ДатаДок="17.10.2024" КодНО="7700" ГодНМ="2024" Период="31" НомерРед="1">
    <СвНП>
      <НПЮЛ НаимОрг="Публичное акционерное общество &quot;Московская городская телефонная сеть&quot;" ИННЮЛ="7710016640" КПП="770701001"/>
    </СвНП>
    <Подписант ПрПодп="2" Долж="Директор департамента">
      <ФИО Фамилия="Корнев" Имя="Дмитрий" Отчество="Александрович"/>
      <СвПред НаимДок="Доверенность б/н от 01.04.2021"/>
    </Подписант>
    <РискОргНМ ОКВЭД="61.10" ОблРиск="01.1" КодРиск="RISK001" НаимРиск="Неплатежные обязательства" ОписРиск="Невыполнение обязательств по кредитным договорам" НапрРиск="2201" КатегорРиск="1" КодНалог="012101" Статья="151" Пункт="1" Подпункт="-" Абзац="-" ВероятРиск="01" ПоследРиск="500000" УровРискОрг="1"/>
  </Документ>
</Файл>

XSD:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2007 sp2 (http://www.altova.com) by VI (GNIVC FNS RF) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
           xmlns:usch="http://www.unisoftware.ru/schematron-extensions"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Файл">
        <xs:annotation>
            <!---*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
            <xs:appinfo>
                <sch:pattern name="Проверка имени файла на соответствие значению атрибута @ИдФайл">
                    <sch:rule context="Файл">
                        <!--  1. Проверка имени файла на соответствие ИдФайл  -->
                        <sch:assert test="usch:getFileName() = @ИдФайл">
                            <usch:error code="0400400007" path="@ИдФайл" value-of-select="@ИдФайл" doc-id-path="usch:getFileName()" doc-id-caption="Файл">Имя файла обмена "<usch:value-of select="usch:getFileName()"/>" не совпадает со значением элемента ИдФайл "<usch:value-of select="@ИдФайл"/>"</usch:error>
                        </sch:assert>
                    </sch:rule>
                </sch:pattern>
            </xs:appinfo>
            <!---*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
            <xs:documentation>Файл обмена</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Документ">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Состав и структура документа</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="СвНП">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Сведения о налогоплательщике</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="НПЮЛ">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:documentation>Сведения об организации - налогоплательщике</xs:documentation>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="НаимОрг" use="required">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>Наименование организации - налогоплательщика (плательщика сбора, плательщика страховых взносов, налогового агента)</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                            <xs:maxLength value="1000"/>
                                                        </xs:restriction>
                                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                                <xs:attribute name="ИННЮЛ" type="ИННЮЛТип" use="required">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>ИНН организации</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                                <xs:attribute name="КПП" type="КППТип" use="required">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>КПП</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="Подписант">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <!---*********************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Присутствие сведений о представителе">
                                            <sch:rule context="Подписант">
                                                <sch:assert test="usch:iif(@ПрПодп=2, count(СвПред)!=0, (count(СвПред)!=0 or count(СвПред)=0))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ПрПодп" value-of-select="@ПрПодп">Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствия) элемента Файл/Документ/Подписант/СвПред при значении элемента ПрПодп, равном "<usch:value-of select="@ПрПодп"/>".</usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---*********************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:documentation>Сведения о лице, подписавшем документ</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="ФИО" type="ФИОТип">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:documentation>Фамилия, имя, отчество руководителя организации (представителя организации)</xs:documentation>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="СвПред" minOccurs="0">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:documentation>Сведения о представителе организации</xs:documentation>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="НаимДок" use="required">
                                                    <xs:annotation>
                                                        <xs:documentation>Наименование и реквизиты документа, подтверждающего полномочия представителя организации</xs:documentation>
                                                    </xs:annotation>
                                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                            <xs:maxLength value="120"/>
                                                        </xs:restriction>
                                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                                </xs:attribute>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="ПрПодп" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Признак лица, подписавшего документ</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:length value="1"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="Долж" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Должность</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                <xs:maxLength value="255"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="РискОргНМ" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <!---*********************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:appinfo>
                                        <sch:pattern name="Присутствие элемента ОКВЭД">
                                            <sch:rule context="РискОргНМ">
                                                <sch:assert test="usch:iif(@КатегорРиск=2, count(@ОКВЭД)!=0, (count(@ОКВЭД)!=0 or count(@ОКВЭД)=0))">
                                                    <usch:error code="0400300003" path="@ОКВЭД" value-of-select="count(@ОКВЭД)">Не выполнено условие присутствия (отсутствия) элемента Файл/Документ/РискОргНМ/ОКВЭД при значении элемента КатегорРиск, равном "<usch:value-of select="@КатегорРиск"/>".</usch:error>
                                                </sch:assert>
                                            </sch:rule>
                                        </sch:pattern>
                                    </xs:appinfo>
                                    <!---*********************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
                                    <xs:documentation>Риски организации, идентифицируемые в целях налогового мониторинга</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="ОКВЭД" type="ОКВЭДТип" use="optional">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Код вида экономической деятельности по ОКВЭД 2</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="ОблРиск" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Область риска</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:length value="4"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="КодРиск" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Код риска организации</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="НаимРиск" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Наименование риска организации</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                <xs:maxLength value="1000"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="ОписРиск" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Описание риска организации</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                <xs:maxLength value="1000"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="НапрРиск" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Направление выявления риска</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:length value="4"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="КатегорРиск" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Категория риска</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:length value="1"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="КодНалог" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Код налога</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:length value="6"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="Статья" use="optional">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Статья Налогового кодекса Российской Федерации</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="Пункт" use="optional">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Пункт статьи Налогового кодекса Российской Федерации</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="Подпункт" use="optional">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Подпункт пункта статьи Налогового кодекса Российской Федерации</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="Абзац" use="optional">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Абзац пункта (подпункта пункта) Налогового кодекса Российской Федерации</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="ВероятРиск" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Вероятность возникновения риска</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:length value="2"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="01"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="02"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="03"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="04"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="05"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="ПоследРиск" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Последствия риска (в тысячах рублей)</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                                <xs:totalDigits value="17"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="УровРискОрг" use="required">
                                        <xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:documentation>Уровень риска организации</xs:documentation>
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:length value="1"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="КНД" use="required">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Код формы документа по КНД</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="КНДТип">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="1125308"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                        <xs:attribute name="ДатаДок" type="ДатаТип" use="required">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Дата формирования документа</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:attribute>
                        <xs:attribute name="КодНО" type="СОНОТип" use="required">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Код налогового органа </xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:attribute>
                        <xs:attribute name="ГодНМ" type="xs:gYear" use="required">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Период налогового мониторинга</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:attribute>
                        <xs:attribute name="Период" use="required">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Код периода документа</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:length value="2"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="21"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="31"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="33"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="30"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                        <xs:attribute name="НомерРед" use="required">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>Порядковый номер редакции</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                    <xs:totalDigits value="2"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="ИдФайл" use="required">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Идентификатор файла</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                        <xs:maxLength value="255"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="ВерсПрог" use="required">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Версия программы, с помощью которой сформирован файл</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="40"/>
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="ВерсФорм" use="required">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Версия формата</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                        <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="5.02"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="ФИОТип">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Фамилия, имя, отчество</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:attribute name="Фамилия" use="required">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Фамилия</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                    <xs:maxLength value="60"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="Имя" use="required">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Имя</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                    <xs:maxLength value="60"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="Отчество" use="optional">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Отчество</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                    <xs:maxLength value="60"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="ИННЮЛТип">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Идентификационный номер налогоплательщика - организации</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="10"/>
            <xs:pattern value="([0-9]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1})[0-9]{8}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="КППТип">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Код причины постановки на учет (КПП) - 5 и 6 знаки от 0-9 и A-Z</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="9"/>
            <xs:pattern value="([0-9]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1})([0-9]{2})([0-9A-Z]{2})([0-9]{3})"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="КНДТип">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Код из Классификатора налоговой документации</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="7"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{7}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="СОНОТип">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Коды из Классификатора системы обозначений налоговых органов</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="4"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{4}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="КБКТип">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Код из Классификатора доходов в бюджет </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="20"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{20}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="ОКВЭДТип">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Код из Общероссийского классификатора видов экономической деятельности</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="8"/>
            <xs:minLength value="2"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{1}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{1}"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="ДатаТип">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Дата в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ (01.01.1900 - 31.12.2099)</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="10"/>
            <xs:pattern value="(((0[1-9]{1}|[1-2]{1}[0-9]{1})\.(0[1-9]{1}|1[0-2]{1}))|((30)\.(01|0[3-9]{1}|1[0-2]{1}))|((31)\.(01|03|05|07|08|10|12)))\.(19[0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2})"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>

Taken from the github repository of the schematron: https://github.com/Schematron/schematron/tree/master/trunk/schematron/code
Maybe someone has already implemented something similar, please tell me how to solve this problem.
Ultimately, we should get an automated API for validating xml using the xcd scheme, xsl files will be taken from the S3 server, arguments will accept two multipart files: xsd and xml.

I suspect that intermediateResult = intermediateResult.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); removes whitespace and that way breaks the XML rules for well-formedness so your generated intermediary XML after the replaceAll is no longer well-formed XML.

Instead of a FileInputStream where somewhere its Charset must be specified, you could explicitly try with a Charset, like new InputSource(new InpputStreamReader or any variation. My guess: some environment setting like file.encoding=UTF-8 is missing.

Sorry, but https://github.com/Schematron/schematron is no longer the best XSLT-based Schematron implementation to use. From its README.md: "new applications of Schematron were advised to use the SchXslt Schematron implementation at https://github.com/schxslt/schxslt." There's also https://github.com/phax/ph-schematron, which is written in Java. See https://github.com/Schematron/awesome-schematron#software for more Schematron implementations.

I think that @MartinHonnen is correct about the whitespace removal, irrespective of where it happens. The error location of lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 13; indicates the first non-name character in an XML declaration that has had whitespace removed: <?xmlversion='1.0'....

Yes, I came to the same conclusion that it's probably complaining about the XML declaration rather than about a processing instruction. They look very similar.

@Martin Honnen
I removed the removal of spaces: intermediateResult = intermediateResult.replaceAll("\s+", ""); and set the encoding UTF-8 everywhere and I get an error:
[Fatal Error] temp_intermediate_result.xml:16:4: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
Intermediate XML is not valid:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/ipkuzne3/MTSProjects/vpnm/SchematronValidation/temp_intermediate_result.xml; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 4; Content is not allowed in trailing section.

I also tried to implement a validator using ph-schematron, but my attempts were unsuccessful, and I also received errors:
WARN com.helger.schematron.xslt.SchematronResourceSCHCache -- The Schematron resource 'path to out.sch' is invalid
Cannot invoke "com.helger.schematron.xslt.ISchematronXSLTBasedProvider.getXSLTDocument()" because "xsltProvider" is null

In addition to the previous comment, I am attaching a stack trace:
13:35:19.561 [main] ERROR com.helger.xml.transform.LoggingTransformErrorListener -- [fatal_error] Transformation fatal error (net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Namespace prefix 'usch' has not been declared)
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation

That is, I register functions:
Configuration config = processor.getUnderlyingConfiguration();
config.registerExtensionFunction(new SchematronFunctions.GetFileNameFunction());
config.registerExtensionFunction(new SchematronFunctions.IifFunction());
But he still doesn't see them

I am not able to visualize all the results your code creates but the error message is clear, the created file temp_intermediate_result.xml is not well-formed, it appears there is (lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 4;) "Content .. in trailing section" so somehow your code creates an intermediary document which isn't proper XML.

It appears to indicate that you have multiple top-level elements or have text after the first element. To be well-formed, your XML needs to have one element that encloses all of the other elements and any text. The only things allowed after the first element are comments, processing instructions, and whitespace.

There is a namespace declaration xmlns:usch="http://www.unisoftware.ru/schematron-extensions" and the use of proprietary/custom functions like sch:assert test="usch:getFileName() = @ИдФайл" from that namespace so perhaps get in touch with the author or creator of the schema/code where the implementation of those functions is to be found.
